# Running Total with Additional Field Filter in Power BI

Tags: filter, powerbi, dax, cumulative-sum

I have created a running total measure in PBI using Dax, however, when the total does not filter by column filter when it is in the table. The running total should sum the balance but then break out into the individual maturity buckets within the table.

Here is the Measure and the resulting table

[image: 1]

I have tried adding extra filters using the FILTER/ALL command to break out the maturity buckets and gotten either the same result or errors. Not sure what else I can do?

Here is a fake sample of data. in the comments i have include the language of the measure.

```
|Date         |Tenor|Balance          |
|-------------|-----|-----------------|
|December 2022|18m  |0.196072326627487|
|December 2022|2y   |0.149643186475954|
|December 2022|3y   |0.180522608363889|
|December 2022|4y   |0.780540306321475|
|December 2022|5y   |0.156029893270158|
|January  2022|18m  |0.512496934496972|
|January  2023|2y   |0.068123785829084|
|January  2023|3y   |0.349971677118287|
```

Comment: Please share your datasets in a copiable format on both of your tables, not as image above! Then I am sure people will react faster to your post! Do not share real data if security is a real concern for you! Just fake data is fine!

Comment: Here is the DAX for the measure that is giving me issues:

`Problematic Running Total = 
CALCULATE(
 SUMX(Sheet1,'Sheet1'[Balance]),
 FILTER(
  ALL('Sheet1'),
  'Sheet1'[Date] <= MAX('Sheet1'[Date])),
        ALL(Sheet1[Tenor])
)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution! I am sorry if I kept you waiting too much!

First, I need to say that your design is not so efficient! You need a full date table with full date values(not only month &year parts)

Here is your calendar table:

[image: Calendar Table]

[image: Data Model View]

Here is the DAX Code you need to write to obtain correct value:

```
Total_Correct = 
    CALCULATE (
    SUM('Callable'[Balance]),
    FILTER ( ALL ( 'Callable'[Date] ), 'Callable'[Date] <= MAX('Callable'[Date])),
    ALL('Calendar')
)
```

[image: Design View]

Comment: thank you this fixed the issue!!! and yes, this was a situation where i was 'building the plane midflight' but i have gone back and added a date table.

one last q, is it possible to just roll the last populated value into next blank month (i.e., have 0,71 populate the Oca 2023 cell, etc.)

Comment: Yes, @KrisP! Good question at the right time! Power BI introduced new function OFFSET() last month, and It brought it into intellisence in December update which was published yesterday! I recommend you to search the offset function. That's your function to solve your problem!